# Two tables with the same CSS properties are rendering different column widths

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to set the widths of my table columns by using a fixed table-layout and by using inline styles on the th elements.

```css
.data-view__table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="right-panel">
        <div class="data-view" id="family-display">
            <h2>Selected Family Overview</h2>
            <div class="data-view__section hidden">
                <h3>Primary Account</h3>
                <table class="data-view__table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:15%;">Name</th>
                            <th style="width:25%;">Address</th>
                            <th style="width:13%;">City</th>
                            <th style="width:5%;">State</th>
                            <th style="width:15%;">Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="primary-contact"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="data-view__section hidden">
                <h3>Other Contacts</h3>
                <table class="data-view__table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:15%;">Name</th>
                            <th style="width:25%;">Address</th>
                            <th style="width:13%;">City</th>
                            <th style="width:5%;">State</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="other-contacts"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Notice how the Name, Address, and City columns all have the same width percentage, and should therefore line up in the picture included at the bottom.

From looking at related posts I've tried using both min-width and width, as well as percentage and pixel based widths for the th elements.

Here is a picture of the two tables on top of each other:

[image]

UPDATE

The number of columns is playing a role. When I adjusted the number of columns in my second table to match the first, the issue was resolved.

Surely there must be a better solution than to add invisible columns to the second table. How do I prevent the table from "auto-expanding" the columns?

Comment: your second table has less columns in it, maybe that's why? If you add up the percentages for the second table they don't add up to 100% so the table is probably expanding some columns to take up the full width. Try adding 2 empty columns that mimic the first table - that may fix the problem (just don't give them titles, but give them the inline styles to look like the first table)

Comment: The same problem happens when I use pixel based widths. Is the best solution to add some hidden columns so that they line up or is there a way to prevent the columns from auto-expanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to specify the width of the E-mail so the total amount will be 100%;
Secondly, a solution can be giving an empty th the remaining width for the second table.

```html
<div class="right-panel">
            <div class="data-view" id="family-display">
                <h2>Selected Family Overview</h2>
                <div class="data-view__section hidden">
                    <h3>Primary Account</h3>
                    <table class="data-view__table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:15%;">Name</th>
                                <th style="width:25%;">Address</th>
                                <th style="width:13%;">City</th>
                                <th style="width:5%;">State</th>
                                <th style="width:15%;">Phone</th>
                                <th style="width:27%;">Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="primary-contact"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="data-view__section hidden">
                    <h3>Other Contacts</h3>
                    <table class="data-view__table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:15%;">Name</th>
                                <th style="width:25%;">Address</th>
                                <th style="width:13%;">City</th>
                                <th style="width:5%;">State</th>
                                <th style="width:42%;"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="other-contacts"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better solution to this, but the one thing I can think of is to add 2 hidden header columns for the second table that mimic the first, the html below should work. Also, I'd add a class (or id, but class is probably better) to each `<th>` and make the css not inline. This will also help you re-use the class for the `th` elements in both the first and second tables

```html
<div class="right-panel">
  <div class="data-view" id="family-display">
    <h2>Selected Family Overview</h2>
    <div class="data-view__section hidden">
      <h3>Primary Account</h3>
      <table class="data-view__table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:15%;">Name</th>
            <th style="width:25%;">Address</th>
            <th style="width:13%;">City</th>
            <th style="width:5%;">State</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="primary-contact"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="data-view__section hidden">
      <h3>Other Contacts</h3>
      <table class="data-view__table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:15%;">Name</th>
            <th style="width:25%;">Address</th>
            <th style="width:13%;">City</th>
            <th style="width:5%;">State</th>
            <th style="width:15%;"></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="other-contacts"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cells in a table will fill the entire width. If you don't like having empty cells, use a `<div>` which is `display:block` and is going to keep the desired width.